# Is there a way to initialize agents in more than one state?

Tags: java, anylogic

I am working on a mosquito model, and for the health status, I use a state chart to define it. I have susceptible, exposed, and infectious states. At the beginning of the model, I need to have 20% of female mosquitoes be infected and 80% susceptible, and all other newborn female mosquitoes should start at susceptible before going to exposed, then infectious, according to the set rules. I used the branch to indicate the condition for distributing the susceptible and infectious, which in turn means that even newborn female mosquitoes are distributed in 80:20. What can I do to have the 20:80 ratio happen only at the start of the model?

[!] [mosquito health status][1]][1]

**[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IV88U.png**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this image, which make all mosquitoes generated after t=0 to be in the same state, while the ones in the beginning of the simulation will check the condition randomTrue(0.8) which will make 80% of the mosquitoes to go to that state

Image in the following link
https://ibb.co/Vm9F51n

Comment: The solution is working, but the problem is that even the mosquitoes in the aquatic stage are taken into account in the health state chart.  I want only female mosquito to be generated after t = 0 to be in susceptible state.

Comment: still the same concept applies, but you need to set up the correct condition